# ORA 06502 Error PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute a simple statement and i got an error while executing.

```
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Addition: '||4+2);
end;
```

> Error:
>   ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>   ORA-06512: at line 2

But when i executed with * operator, it worked fine.

```
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Addition: '||4*2);
end;
```

Does anyone know the reason behind it?

Comment: Try using brackets `dbms_output.put_line('Addition: '||(4+2));`

Comment: hi @Vignesh has any of these answers been helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When an answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Comment: the second answer (Operator Precedence) is correct. You should accept it

Answer (score 10):

It is due the [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators001.htm#SQLRF51153).

Multiplication has higher precedence than concatenation. So, `'Addition: '||4*2` evaluates to `'Addition: '||8` and to `'Addition: 8'`.

Addition has same precedence as concatenation and operators with equal precedence are evaluated from left to right.
So, `'Addition: '||4+2` evaluates to `'Addition: 4' + 2`, which subsequently fails as you cannot add number to characters.

In such cases, you should always use brackets to explicitly specify the order of evaluation, like this `'Addition: '|| (4+2)`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the actual problems is that this code is relying on implicit data type conversion by the Oracle kernel. **Always** use explicit data type conversion. For instance:

begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Addition: ' || to_char(4+2));
end;

There are many other cases where you will run into unexpected errors due to implicit data type conversion. Like in equal joining a varchar with number. As long as the varchar contains only numeric values, it works fine (although maybe slow due to index not being used). But as soon as you insert one row with non numeric data, you will run into an error when that row is being hit. Making the data type conversion explicit ensures that Oracle does not by accident chose the wrong side of an equal join to convert.

Comment: if that is the case then this should also give the error `code` begin
dbms_output.put_line( 4+2 || 'Addition:' );
end; `code`

Comment: It's not the implicit data type conversion(of course it takes place, no doubts about it, but it's not the main reason) that causes the `ORA-06502:` in OP's example. The cause of the error is the same precedence of operators. Addition (`+`) and concatenation (`||`) operators have the same precedence and being evaluated from the left to right in the expression. So we end up trying to add number 2 to `Addition: 4` *string*, and that operation causes the `ORA-06502:` error to be raised.

Comment: Yes, operator precedence causes the error initially, but I prefer to avoid thinking about operator precedence and other problems by applying good coding style and quality measures. At our company, we prefer to avoid problems like these by requiring preventive actions even when the extra characters typed are not always necessarily [end of holy war :-)]